# How to tell php-fpm to send php error log to the nginx error log?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

When I am using apache/mod_php, the PHP error will appear in the apache's error log.

Now, I am using php-fpm with nginx via fcgi, is it possible to have the PHP error log in the nginx error log as well?

So far the only solution is to use external file as defined in the php.ini

```
error_log = /tmp/php_errors.log
```

But I want them in the nginx error log for the ease of maintenance.

Comment: You could also just set php's error log to the same file as the nginx one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1. Unset PHP's `error_log` directive in `php.ini`. This will cause it to log to standard error, which nginx will then log to its own error log.
2. Set `catch_workers_output = yes` in your php-fpm configuration `php-fpm.conf`, to ensure that the FPM SAPI doesn't discard standard error.